# How to create move/resize animations in Android?

Tags: android, animation

Does someone know about Android animations? I want to create something like following:

- I have a big image in the center of my device screen;
- this image becomes small (by animation) and goes to the corner of my device screen;

Its something like in this bellow sequence:

[image]

Any hints would be very appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ViewPropertyAnimator`, with methods like `scaleXBy()` and `translateYBy()`. You get a `ViewPropertyAnimator` by calling `animate()` on a `View`, on API Level 11+. If you are supporting older devices, [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com) offers a near-workalike backport.

You might also wish to read:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. Surelly, this is of great help!

Answer (score 7):

I have a class with the simultaneous rotation and movement. It's costly but it works on all API versions.

```
public class ResizeMoveAnimation extends Animation {
    View view; 
    int fromLeft; 
    int fromTop; 
    int fromRight;
    int fromBottom;
    int toLeft; 
    int toTop; 
    int toRight;
    int toBottom;

    public ResizeMoveAnimation(View v, int toLeft, int toTop, int toRight, int toBottom) {
        this.view = v;
        this.toLeft = toLeft;
        this.toTop = toTop;
        this.toRight = toRight;
        this.toBottom = toBottom;

        fromLeft = v.getLeft();
        fromTop = v.getTop();
        fromRight = v.getRight();
        fromBottom = v.getBottom();

        setDuration(500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

        float left = fromLeft + (toLeft - fromLeft) * interpolatedTime;
        float top = fromTop + (toTop - fromTop) * interpolatedTime;
        float right = fromRight + (toRight - fromRight) * interpolatedTime;
        float bottom = fromBottom + (toBottom - fromBottom) * interpolatedTime;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.leftMargin = (int) left;
        p.topMargin = (int) top;
        p.width = (int) ((right - left) + 1);
        p.height = (int) ((bottom - top) + 1);

        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we call this resize animation with the view as mentioned